# I need guidance including JS into a HTML file with <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need some guidance, since I'm stuck and can't figure out how to simply include JS code in a html file. I've read multiple threads and articles, and have been struggling with getting this to work.

I have copied the HTML/CSS/JS code from codepen and pasted it into a html file.
https://codepen.io/jona09h3/pen/mdKOGxR

The issue is the JS code doesn't execute.
Please take a look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Typewriter</title>
<script>
class TypeWriter {
  constructor(headline, selector) {
    /*The text content*/
    this.heading = headline;

    /*The element with the text content*/
    this.elemSelector = selector;

    /*I'm showing the "cursor" using borderRight.*/
    gsap.set(".blinkCursorEnd", {
      borderRight: "2px solid black"
    });

    /*Set this width to the size of the startingCursor, to make it show.*/
    gsap.set(this.elemSelector, {
      width: "2px"
    });

    gsap.set(".blinkCursorStart", {
      borderRight: "2px solid black",
      opacity: 1
    });

    /*The starting cursor animation. When complete to the actual typeeffect.*/
    gsap.to(".blinkCursorStart", {
      borderRightColor: "transparent",
      duration: 0.5,
      /*Change repeat to make the initial animation shorter or longer*/
      repeat: 10,
      yoyo: true,
      ease: "steps(1)",
      onComplete: () => {
        this.makeTypeWritingEffect();
      }
    });
  }

  makeTypeWritingEffect() {
    /*Hiding the first cursor*/
    gsap.to(".blinkCursorStart", {
      opacity: 0
    });

    /*Showing the second cursor, making it run in an infinite loop*/
    gsap.to(".blinkCursorEnd", {
      borderRightColor: "transparent",
      duration: 0.5,
      repeat: -1,
      yoyo: true,
      /*Change/remove this ease if you want the cursor to fade instead.*/
      ease: "steps(1)"
    });

    /*The actual text being animated.*/
    gsap.to(this.elemSelector, {
      width: `${this.heading.length + 0.2}ch`,
      duration: 2,
      ease: `steps(${this.heading.length})`
    });
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  let typeWriter = new TypeWriter(
    document.querySelector("h2").textContent,
    document.querySelector("h2")
  );
});

</script>
<style>
    h2{
   white-space: nowrap;
  
  /* Hides the text content of h2 as default. The whole content would show right away with this not here.  */
   overflow: hidden;
  
  /*It needs a monospaced font to work best. Have tested it with Source Code Pro aswell.*/
  font-family: monospace;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>
<!-- The starting blink cursor -->
 <span class="blinkCursorStart"> </span>
   This is a typing test.
  
<!-- The end cursor  -->
<span class="blinkCursorEnd"> </span>
</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried adding:
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` following the title tag. And moving the `<script>...</script>` to the body instead of header. No difference.

I cannot use the `<script src="...` attribute and need the code to be in the html file.

What have I not understood and what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks,

Comment: That script is using the `gsap` library. 

Have you included it ?
Seems like the codepen is using `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js`

Comment: in addition to what @WilomGfx said, since you included your JS into the header you need to use defer Attribute in the script tag, otherwise you need to put the script at the end of your html before the closing body tag

Comment: @mmh4all - Please note that per the [warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attributes) on MDN, `defer` can't be used on inline scripts. Also the code already waits for the window `load` event to fire before modifying the DOM, so can be loaded in the head section with no ill effect.

Comment: @WilomGfx - Thanks, that solved it.

If a codepen doesn't link to an external .js file does that mean I dont't need to either ?

  Here is one that doesn´t reference a .js file  <https://codepen.io/georgehastings/pen/PbLKYO>